# How to call one template from child theme while another is in parent?

Tags: wordpress

I want to use this code:

```
<?php
$post = $wp_query->post;

if ( in_category( 'video' ) ) {
  include( TEMPLATEPATH.'/single-video.php' );
} 
else {
  include( TEMPLATEPATH.'/single.php' );
}
?>
```

I put this in single.php in child theme directory, and while its correctly calling single.php from parent directory, it is not calling single-video.php from child theme directory because of the incorection TEMPLATEPATH.'/.

What should I put instead of that to call signle-video.php template from the child theme directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the associated function get_template_directory() path to the active child theme. The constant TEMPLATEPATH get the path to the parent theme